# How to search for a variable in a column with SQLite3 in the same way that %{variable}% should work

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I've been struggling to get this working. I'm trying to make a discord bot for an RP server, and this is specifically for character reservations. I want it so that when someone tries to reserve a character it searches if said character is already in the database, and if there isn't a column with said character it'll create one, hence creating a reservation (the reservation time is 30 seconds just for testing it)

The code below is working, but the problem is if someone doesn't enter it perfectly (for example if they just entered their first name, but then someone entered first and last name), it would create another entry and just cause confusion.

```py
@app_commands.command(name="reservation_request", description="wip")
    async def ReqReservation(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, character: str) -> None:
        todayDate = datetime.today()
        # todayDate = todayDate.replace(minute=0, second = 0, microsecond= 0, hour=todayDate.hour + 1)
        db = sqlite3.connect("index.db")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT character_name FROM reservationIndex WHERE character_name LIKE '{character}'")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO reservationIndex(character_name, user_id, reservation_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
            val = (character, interaction.user.id, (todayDate + timedelta(seconds=30)))
            cursor.execute(sql,val)
            await interaction.response.send_message("Character successfully reserved!", ephemeral= True)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("That character is already reserved.", ephemeral=True)
        
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

I have tried adding percentages all around the variable and it didn't do anything. I even tried replacing `cursor.execute(f"SELECT character_name FROM reservationIndex WHERE character_name LIKE '{character}'")` with `cursor.execute(f"SELECT character_name FROM reservationIndex WHERE ? LIKE ?", ('character_name', '%'+character+'%'))`, as I'd seen another question asking a similar thing and I hoped it would work, but on testing that just made it so everything was accepted as a reservation, even including copy and pastes of the very same name.

Comment: Note: You code currently has a [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) vulnerability in the line where you are using an f-string to parameterize your query.